# How to run command prompt programs on C#?

Tags: c#, command-prompt

I would like to know if there is a way to run a command prompt program such as "C:/temp/mactimes.pl" which the command "perl mactimes.pl" could be run in the C# program.

I have looked through "process.start" class but it only detects .exe format programs. Therefore I need the "perl" command to startup the perl script.

Please do give advices! Thanks!!!

Comment: Oh, I am sorry for providing you with a wrong answer. While searching for a solution I came across an article Make Your Existing Perl Apps .NET-compliant  http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/8015/1954 .I will let you know if i find a concrete answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If perl is in the system PATH:

```
Process.Start("perl.exe", "C:\\temp\\mactimes.pl");
```

Otherwise you will need to enter the full path to it.

Comment: Does not seem to work gives me an error of "system cannot find file specified". I tried running the command purely on the CMD and it works....

Comment: In that case, I said to specify the full path to the perl executable. Your code might look like this: Process.Start("C:\\perl\\bin\\perl.exe", "C:\\temp\\mactimes.pl");

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "cmd.exe" as the executable. And feed it with anything you want after "/C" key for example.